# Error importing own Swift Cocoa Touch Framework in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have problems importing my own Swift Cocoa Touch Framework in an Swift app.
The Framework contains a Swift File, the Header File and the Info.plist.
The Project, in which I created the Framework contains also a test app as another target (Single View Application).

The testing in the Test App worked fine. I imported the Framework in my Swift Test App with

```
import MyUtilities
```

and it worked. But when I copy the .framework file to another Projekt and add it to "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", I get an error when importing it.

```
Cannot load underlying module for 'MyUtilities'
```

I use the .framework file in the debug-iphoneos folder after building the framework with my iPhone selected and also build and run my framework with my iPhone selected in the new project.

I also tried it with a script from the internet, which should create a universal.framework file for both, simulator and device. It showed the same error.

The weird thing is, that I get the error above, but Xcode says Build Succeeded and also runs the app on my iPhone **and** lets me use code of my framework... So practically the import works, but I don't get completition and cannot see the documentation of my framework... Probably it's a bug of Xcode...

So to my question: Does anybody knows, how to fix that, so I see code completition in Xcode again and get rid of this error?

Here is the script, I downloaded to export the framework for universal use:

```
#CONFIG=${CONFIGURATION}
CONFIG=Release

# Step 1. Make sure the output directory exists
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-universal
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 3. Copy the framework structure to the universal folder. Subsequently copy the files of the swiftmodule (in Modules directory) of -iphonesimulator to the swiftmodule of universal framework directory.

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

### Here are a few screenshots of my Project in which I coded the framework:

The script, which exports the universal framework:
[image]

The dependencies of the test app:
[image]

No error, when I use my framework in the test app:
[image]

### And from the new project, in which I tried to import the framework:

The framework is correctly linked:
[image]

The error when trying to import:
[image]

The Output message when running the code from my framework:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not enabling access to the header files of the framework. I just struggled with this issue for quite a while. In Build Settings, I think you need to refer to the framework. If you are building your framework in your project that is using the framework, this should work:

Now for the coup de grace: Under Build Settings, search for Framework Search Paths. And add in:

```
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/YourFrameworkName.framework
```

Look at [How Do I Create a Development Framework In iOS Including Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816507/how-do-i-create-a-development-framework-in-ios-including-swift) for more details.

Comment: I wanted to try your solution, but the problem was already fixed. I think it was just a little bug of my Xcode version... Everything works fine now. But thanks for your answer :-)